# Break up horizontal longtable

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, longtable, xtable, scale

I tried to figure this out on my own. However, nothing seemed to work. I have a super long table, but its formatted differently than a normal table as it is oriented horizontally. If i can i would like to keep it that way. Currently the problem is that it

1. one row to wide for the horizontal page. I would like to scale it in a way that the width/ height fits on one page.
2. The table just keeps going out of the page on the right side/ top. If possible i would like to break it up so it flows over multiple pages.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is what i have so far:

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}lllccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc@{}}
\toprule
Dimensionen   englisch &
  Dimensionen   deutsch &
  Definition &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{BDD7EE}1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{BDD7EE}2} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{BDD7EE}3} &
.... and a way more removed because marked as spam
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9BC2E6}29} \\* \midrule
\endfirsthead
%
\multicolumn{32}{c}%
{{\bfseries Table \thetable\ continued from previous page}} \\
\endhead
%
\bottomrule
\endfoot
%
\endlastfoot
%
Timeliness &

.....a thousand &; SE marked it as spam
   \\* \bottomrule
\caption{Dimensionen der Wissensqualität}
\label{tab:Wissensqualittsdimensionen}\\
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}lllccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc@{}}
\toprule
Dimensionen   englisch &
  Dimensionen   deutsch &
  Definition &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{BDD7EE}1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{BDD7EE}2} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{BDD7EE}3} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}4} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}5} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{BDD7EE}6} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{BDD7EE}7} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}8} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{BDD7EE}9} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{BDD7EE}10} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}11} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}12} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{BDD7EE}13} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{BDD7EE}14} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{BDD7EE}15} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{BDD7EE}16} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}17} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9BC2E6}18} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9BC2E6}19} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9BC2E6}20} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9BC2E6}21} &
.... and a few more removed because marked as spam

\endfirsthead
%
\multicolumn{32}{c}%
{{\bfseries Table \thetable\ continued from previous page}} \\
\endhead
%
\bottomrule
\endfoot
%
\endlastfoot
%
Timeliness &
  Aktualität &
  aktuell &
  x &
.....a thousand &; SE marked it as spam

   \\* \bottomrule
\caption{Dimensionen der Wissensqualität}
\label{tab:Wissensqualittsdimensionen}\\
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
```

And it looks like this:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTjTJ.png]

EDIT: Thanks to everyone who tried to help i figured out a workaround, maybe it can help someone. I used the geometry package to change the margins of the sections i wanted the table on so the width of the table was fitting on one page. After i broke up the table in 4 sections in order to fit the height of the page. Maybe its not the most elegant solution. However, it works. Sorry if i wasnt clear enough in my description and thanks again for everyones help!

Heres how it looks now:
[image: Solution]

Comment: it is more or less impossible to help if you provide no example code, but what do you want to happen? If  you have 32 columns with `x` it may be just  about readable but if you have that many columns wide enough for words like `responsiveness` then you will have to use a font that is so small to be unreadable if you want to fit it on a page.

Comment: Please provide a complete small document you don't need to provide thousands of lines since your issue seems to be already present in line 1 being too wide even for landscape.

Comment: If you make the third column narrower and allow linebreaks in the corresponding cells (for example by using a `p`type column wou should be able to save some space. You could also use abbreviations/symbols for the words in the last columns to save even more space. Lastly you could also space space by combining the first two columns since they basically contain the same information, just in two different languages.

Comment: Does TeX.SE really mark anything as spam??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small example table that illustrates my previous suggestions on how to make your table narrower in order to fit it into the available space.

I combined the two "Dimensionen" columns sice they both contain basically the same information, just in two different languages. Using `X` type columns from `xltabular` I made sure to allow linebreaks in the "Dimensionen" and "Definition"  columns. Using a `wc` type column, i made sure all following 32 columns have the same width while being horizontally centered. To save some more space, I reduced the font size to `\footnotesize` and the horizontal white space between columns (`\tabcolsep`) from the original `6pt` to `2pt`. If you use a different documentclass with a larger textblock, you might be able to increase the font size to `\small`. Lastly, I replaced the words in the last 32 columns with single letters and used the `threeparttablex` package to explain these single letter abbreviations below the table. With the current settings, this explanatory part will be repeated on every page of the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\footnotesize
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}[flushleft, para]
a)~some text; b)~some other text; c)~more text; d)~more text; e)~more text; 
\end{TableNotes}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{*{2}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X@{\hspace{2\tabcolsep}}} *{32}{wc{1em}}}
\caption{Dimensionen der Wissensqualität} \label{tab:Wissensqualittsdimensionen}\\
\toprule
Dimensionen englisch (deutsch) & Definition & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 32 \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption{Dimensionen der Wissensqualität - continued from previous page}\\
\toprule
Dimensionen englisch (deutsch) & Definition & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 32 \\
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes
\endfoot
Interpretability (Interpretierbarkeit) & entsprechende Sprache, Symbole, Einheiten 
  & x  & a) & x  & x  & x  & x  & x  & a) 
  & x  & x  & x  & b) & x  & x  & x  & a) 
  & x  & x  & x  & a) & x  & x  & x  & c) 
  & x  & x  & x  & x  & x  & x  & x  & x  \\
\addlinespace
Concise representation (Prägnante Darstellung)  & kompakt dargestellt 
  & x  & x  & d) & x  & a) & x  & x  & x 
  & x  & x  & x  & b) & x  & x  & x  & e) 
  & x  & x  & x  & a) & x  & x  & d) & x 
  & x  & x  & x  & x  & x  & x  & x  & x  \\
\end{xltabular}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution would be very elegant. However, i figured out a workaround by narrowing the margins and breaking up the table. Thank you again for taking the time to help!